# Toast notification without network - windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to implement the "toast" notification inside my windows phone application. I'm implementing push message's, but I want them to show always. No matter if the application is running or not. The push notification will handle it when the application is closed, but not when it is running. Also if I create a shelltoast manually it won't show.

To make it more difficult I can't use any external dll's. I only want to use code. What would be the best way to do this?

I already know about the ToastNotificationRecieved event. I want to know how to implement it so that it will show a "toast" like message without using a framework

Answer (score 0):

A Windows Phone application won't show a toast notification while the application is running, so it's up to you to intercept the notification and respond accordingly - typically by updating the UI of the app in place versus displaying a toast per se.

You'll want to implement the [ShellToastNotificationReceivedEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel.shelltoastnotificationreceived%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) to handle the scenario where the app is in the foreground.

Comment: I already know about this event, but I want a way to display the message that I intercept. I know that there are frameworks who have implemented a kind of message that displays like a toast message. I'm looking for a way to create that kind of message